# How can I upload multiple images to an s3 bucket in a lambda function using node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am not very familiar with node and trying to upload an array of media objects to an s3 bucket using an AWS Lambda node function.

the payload has an album which is an array of key/data dictionaries.  My code is as below but I'm certain this is wrong.

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./app');

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var s3Params = {
    Bucket: 'bucketid',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(event);
    var body = JSON.parse(event.body);

    if (typeof body.album !== 'undefined' && body.album) {
        body.album.forEach(function (value) {
            var data = body.album.mediaString;
            let mediaData = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
            var mediaKey = body.album.mediaKey;
            try {
                s3Params = {
                    Bucket: 'bucketID',
                    Key: mediaKey,
                    Body: mediaData
                };
                try {
                    const stored = await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();
                    console.log("stored successfully");
                    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) };
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("error storing");
                    console.log(err);
                    return { error: err };
                }
            } catch (err) {
                return { error: err };
            }
        });
        return { body: JSON.stringify(data) };
    } else {
        return { error: 'error'};
    }
};
```

I have an error that s3 not found.  Just wondering if I'm going about this all wrong.

When I only upload one image with the following code everything works fine:

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./app');

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
 
 var s3Params = {
  Bucket: 'bucketID',
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
 };
  
 exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

   var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
   
   var data = body.mediaString;
   let mediaData = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
   var mediaKey = body.mediaKey;
 
   try {
    s3Params = {
      Bucket: 'bucketID',
      Key: mediaKey,
      Body: mediaData
      
    };
    try {
      const stored = await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();
      console.log("stored successfully");
      return { body: JSON.stringify(data) };
    } catch (err) {
     console.log("error storing");
      console.log(err);
      return { error: err };
    }
     
   } catch (err) {
     return { error: err };
   }
 };
```

Comment: there are some config [options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html) I think you are missing

Comment: the options are correct and I'm able to save one image using slightly different code.  The problem I think is the forEach.  it doesn't recognize the s3 in there.  I'm really not familiar with node at all and only have these two functions in my app in node.

Comment: are you sure that each bucket exists?

Comment: that's not the issue.  I edited the code and you it works fine with just one image.  The code itself is not correct.

Comment: can you show the error?

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token s3 is one problem.  This is next to const stored = await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();

Comment: then it sounds like a context problem. Try not using the fat arrow on the export